# How to filter by a relationship attribute when using paginate

Tags: php, laravel, relationship, query-builder

I want to implement a search function with latest status of booking.

key structure of tables: 

bookings

- id

booking_statuses

- name (enum: Pending, Done)

- booking_id (FK to bookings table)

 And I have a relationship call 'status_history'


 I tried below method, but isn't work. How can I limit first row before execute where query?

```
$keyword = 'Done';
$bookings->whereHas('status_history', function ($q) use ($keyword) {
    $q->latest()->where('name', 'LIKE', '%' . $keyword . '%');
})->paginate(10);
```

Comment: do you get any errors plus include the relationship, latests has no effect on a whereHas. try to explain in detail what you are trying to do?

Comment: In my website, it will display the latest status of the booking, and now I have a search bar to filter booking by latest status.